# Find a Book About Practical approach to learn RUP

Tags: design-patterns, uml, rup

I want to learn RUP but don't find a practical book!. I read the "Guide to the Unified Process featuring UML, Java and Design Patterns" by John Hunt But this book is so brief.
is there a book that learns the RUP step by step with UML diagram(each discipline)?

tnx.

Answer (score 2):

If you define practical as "helps me get my work done," I don't find anything practical about RUP, prescriptive maybe not not particularly practical.  If you are just interested in picking up a methodology and don't have to learn RUP, then I suggest any of many different books on Agile Methods.   Highsmith's [Agile Software Development Ecosystems](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201760436) is a good overview of several.  If you're really stuck on RUP, then you may want to consider the [Agile Unified Process](http://www.ambysoft.com/unifiedprocess/agileUP.html).

**The** book on RUP is probably [The Rational Unified Process: An Introduction](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321197704).  You may want to check it out of your local library.  I can't say I remember it well enough to give you a recommendation.

Answer (score 0):

What about this one:

[The Rational Unified Process Made Easy: A Practitioner's Guide to the RUP](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321166094)

Hope that helps

Comment: thanks, i read this a few month ago.

Answer (score 0):

Well, 
Larman apply a modified-adapted version of RUP [in an agile manner] in his book

**Applying UML & Patterns: Introduction to Object-Oriented Analysis & Design, & Iterative Development** Craig Larman

step by step....